# Edit my Add to cart button for variable product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have three versions of this code in my site to product 3 buttons ( 1x quantity, 3x quantity and 10x quantity). My products are variable. The code didn't work until I removed this line `if( ! $product->is_type('simple') ) return;` . With this line removed, should it be replaced with something else for variable products to ensure the code is complete properly?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'additional_simple_add_to_cart_10', 20 );

function additional_simple_add_to_cart_10() {
    global $product;

// Only for simple product type
    if( ! $product->is_type('simple') ) return;  // Removed this line 


$href = '?add-to-cart=' . esc_attr( $product->get_id() ) . '&quantity=10';
$class = 'ingle_add_to_cart_button-10 button alt';
$style = 'display: inline-block; margin-top: 12px;';
$button_text = __( "10 Tickets", "woocommerce" );

// Output
echo '<br><a rel="no-follow" href="'.$href.'" class="'.$class.'" style="'.$style.'">'.$button_text.'</a>';

}

// Redirect to checkout after add to basket 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'misha_skip_cart_redirect_checkout' );

function misha_skip_cart_redirect_checkout( $url ) {
    return wc_get_checkout_url();
}
```

Comment: If you only want to apply this for variable products you can replace 'simple' with 'variable' in the if condition  `// Only for variable product type 
if( ! $product->is_type('variable') ) return;` || product types = ( 'simple', 'grouped', 'variable', 'external' )

Comment: What about all product types? I added your suggestion and now my button doesn't work lol  @7uc1f3r

Comment: If you want to apply this for all product types you have to remove the if ... line completely

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate this help.